# duplicate classes in commons-collections and commons-beanutils

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

There are four duplicate classes in two Maven artifacts from Apache: `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3` and `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1`:

```
org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack
org.apache.commons.collections.Buffer
org.apache.commons.collections.BufferUnderflowException
org.apache.commons.collections.FastHashMap
```

Is it possible to replace one of them with some other artifact to avoid this duplication? I tried to google but didn't find any solution. Rather annoying problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In this case, the problem isn't maven or exclusions (which usually is the issue) but you are using the wrong version of beanutils most likely.

There is a version of the beanutils jar that has bean collections included and one that does not. The maven dependencies for the beanutils with bean collections includes commons collections. If you are using commons collections yourself, use the core version of and include commons collections in the maven dependencies.

This is where it is explained a bit: http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

That page says this:

> ```
> commons-beanutils.jar - contains everything
> commons-beanutils-core.jar - excludes Bean Collections classes
> commons-beanutils-bean-collections.jar - only Bean Collections classes
>
> The main commons-beanutils.jar has an optional dependency on Commons Collections
> ```

Comment: The situation has changed with beanutils 1.9: commons-beanutils-core and commons-beanutils-bean-collections are no longer being released.  Instead, the offending classes have been removed from commons-beanutils.jar.  So just make sure your commons-beanutils is up to date.

Comment: On the opposite - commons-beanutils-bean-collections is the jar that you're looking for. Free of the offending classes

Comment: So basically what's happening is you're pulling in two versions either from a misconfigured jar (pulls in both, which is redundant), or from multiple dependencies where one pulls in one version, the other the other, collision!  I'd call that a "weird release system" problem of the commons-beanutils, as it were, since maven doesn't handle that pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) it's tells to use exclude tag

**UPDATE**

look at this to [link2](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>classworlds:classworlds</exclude>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                  <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you also know how to exclude specific classes from a JAR? :) exclusion doesn't help since these four classes are not the only classes in these JARs

Comment: Maven won't allow excluding specific classes--only specific transitive dependencies which would usually be whole jars.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what's happening is you're pulling in two versions either from a misconfigured jar (pulls in both, which is redundant), or from multiple dependencies where one pulls in one version, the other the other, collision!  I'd call that a "weird release system" problem of the commons-beanutils, as it were, since maven doesn't handle that pattern easily...a fix for me was to bump the version of my dependency that pulls in both versions (in my case "commons-configuration"), or to manually specify a particular version of `commons-configuration`:

So this `mvn dependency:tree`:

```
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile (version managed from 3.2)
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
```

became this:

```
[INFO] +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3:compile
```

though according to the comments on the other answer, bumping "something" to a version that uses commons-beanutil 1.9+ would also do it.

Answer (score -1):

Exclude the collection package from the beanutils JAR, it worked for me :)