# How to deduplicate beanutils dependencies with commons-beanutils?

Tags: dependencies, sbt, sbt-assembly, maven-shade-plugin

I have a project with several dependencies, which ultimately lead to 
depending on the following (I got these from [sbt-dependency-graph plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)):

- `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.7.0`
- `commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:1.8.0`

As a consequence, when I try to build a fat JAR using [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly), it fails with deduplication errors as:

```
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/someuser/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/someuser-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:org/apache/commons/beanutils/BasicDynaBean.class
[error] /Users/someuser/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:org/apache/commons/beanutils/BasicDynaBean.class
```

Since I need both dependencies, I tried to shade one of them using the following rule:

```
ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.beanutils.**" -> "shadedstuff.beanutils.@1").inLibrary("commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.7.0").inAll
```

But then I get the following error:

```
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/someuser/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/someuser-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:shadedstuff/beanutils/BasicDynaBean.class
[error] /Users/someuser/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:shadedstuff/beanutils/BasicDynaBean.class
```

As if the shading process is applied to both artifacts. How to shade a specific artifact?

Comment: For the shade plugin see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402745/duplicate-classes-in-commons-collections-and-commons-beanutils

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I need both dependencies, I tried to shade one of them using the following rule:
>
> ```
> ShadeRule.rename("org.apache.commons.beanutils.**" -> "shadedstuff.beanutils.@1").inLibrary("commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.7.0").inAll
> ```

Shading is a contributed feature on sbt-assembly, which basically integrates with [Jar Jar Links](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/), so I'm not expert on this.

Having said that, I think `.inAll` defeats the purpose of your `.inLibrary(...)` call. Maybe the way I described it on the README wasn't clear enough.

I think what you want to do is to put `inLibrary(...)` for commons-beanutils 1.7.0 **and** all of its callers who is referring to commons-beanutils 1.7.0 code as `org.apache.commons.beanutils.**` (in this case Hadoop?)

Comment: Indeed. Removing `.inAll` fixes the issue. I misunderstood the documentation, but now everything seems pretty clear. Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: @ale64bit, Can you please a snippet of the working `build.sbt` file. I have a similar issue while depending  `org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3`.